# PHP - differentiate values from hexadecimal to string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which value is 123, like: `$string = '123';` and my hex value, which is `$hex = bin2hex($string);` and the return is 313233. When i convert to string again, using `hex2bin()`, it returns 123 correctly. But when i try to make a "compare" it always returns both like a hexadecimal value.

I know that each number, both 1, 2 and 3 are part of hexadecimal table, but, is there a way that can i differentiate each one ? I'd already searched something about it, but i got no solution.

I'm sorry if this question is poor. But it will really helped me. Besides, it's a doubt that i have.

My php code:

```
<?php
$string = '123';
$hex = bin2hex($string);
if(hex2bin($hex)){
    echo 'hex';
}else{
    echo 'not hex';
}
?>
```

Comment: `$string = 123;` is not a string, you need single quotes or double quotes surrounding `123`, like so `$string = '123';`.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if every character in a string is a hex character?  Is that what's going on here?

Comment: I tried with quotes @Tiffany, but still doesn't work. But, i got what you said, i will update my question

Comment: I dont see any comparisons taking place in your example. `hex2bin` returns a string which will evaluate to true so 'hex' will always be shown.

Comment: @castis like i said, i don't if what i done, it's correct. I presumed that method `hex2bin()` to understand what would be hexadecimal or not

Comment: @castis Exactly. Also, there's no comparison being done in your code.

Comment: Do you mean to use `dechex()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)

Comment: @WillardSolutions no, i want the code determine what is hexadecimal and what is not. Like i said, i know that 1,2 and 3 are numbers of hexadecimal table. But i want to do something, in lay way of saying, like: `$string` outputs `echo 'this not a hex, this is a string'` and `$hex` outputs `echo 'this is a hexadecimal !'`

Comment: @ChigozieOrunta how can i do that so ? Can you give me some examples ?

Comment: @NigelRen i want identify what is string and what is hexadecimal value

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are looking for the `ctype_xdigit()` function, which returns true if all the individual letters in your string are hexadecimal digits, otherwise false.

You just have to pass the string as a parameter:

```
if (ctype_xdigit($hex_string)){
    echo 'hex';
} else {
    echo 'not hex';
}
```

What you did in your original code was converting binary numbers to hexadecimals and then the other way round. It's no surprise that it didn't give you the expected results, as `123` is not a binary number, in the input there couldn't be any other digits than `0` and `1`.

Comment: partially worked, let say if try verify if the `$string` is a hexadecimal. It still returns that is a hex, but when i remove the quotes. Returns that is not a hex, like i want. The problem is, the value setting `$string` must to be a string, 'cause, let say that i vary something like: '123a', '321bc' whatever... there will be some that it will return like hex, which I do not want

Comment: I don't understand. Why are the quotes bothering you? You can't work with hexadecimals without quotes as they would be handled as if they were decimal numbers.

Comment: the quotes are not bothering me. I just did not know that by taking the quotation marks the `ctype_xdigit ()` would read as decimal. But anyway, this way is not working, it still understands that `$ string` is hex and not string.

Comment: All the hexadecimal numbers can be strings as well, and there is no way to determine whether `abcdef` is a string or a hexadecimal number. It depends only on the context and usage. So basically there are two cases: 1. there are only digits `0-1` and letters `a-f` used, which means that this can be a string or a hex number; 2. there are other characters as well, in which case it obviously can't be a hexadecimal number, but it is still a string.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, functions don't work as you think they do, i.e. `if(hex2bin($hex))` is kind of nonsense when used like that. (it returns "123" which will always evaluate as "true")

secondly, consider using `ctype_xdigit` which does what you want

```
<?php
$string = '123';
$hex = bin2hex($string);
if(ctype_xdigit($hex)){
    echo 'is a hex value (was originally '+hex2bin($hex)+')';
}else{
    echo 'not hex';
}
?>
```

Comment: partially worked, let say if try verify if the $string is a hexadecimal. It still returns that is a hex, but when i remove the quotes. Returns that is not a hex, like i want. The problem is, the value setting $string must to be a string, 'cause, let say that i vary something like: '123a', '321bc' whatever... there will be some that it will return like hex, which I do not want

Comment: It does work. But you have a long way to go. When you "remove the quotes" you are incorrectly changing the implicit datatype from a `string` to an `int` this is because PHP usually isn't running in such a way as to `enforce strict typing` and it handles it for you. this is totally outside the scope of the question. Next, ALL legal hexadecimal strings will be accepted so long as they are alphanumeric STRINGS with no greater that `1-0 then A-F`. There is nothing you can do about that other than register the string you want and check if they are in the register on the way out. Which is not ur q

Comment: I see. But there is no way I can check the `$string` and say: 'this is a string and not a hex' ?

Comment: yes there is, because a hex IS a STRING. You use the `ctype_xdigit ` method to ascertain whether a STRING is representing a legal hex, but you have to absorb the elementary notion that hex is *not* a formal datatype in PHP. All hex are represented by STRINGS in php. As are binary numbers.

Comment: and as I said before, if you want to `register` only legal hex's then you would need to "register" them into an array on the way in and "look them up" on the way out.